# ModiTect not finding module dependency

Tags: maven, javafx, vlcj, moditect

I am trying to use moditect to build with **vlcj** which is not built with **jlink**.

After the *maven clean* command, then *maven install*, I get the following error:

```
Module uk.co.caprica.vlcj.osx.stubs not found, required by uk.co.caprica.vlcj
```

After that I found **uk.co.caprica.vlcj.osx.stubs**, added it to **dependencies** and to **additionalDependencies** to the **vlcj** module, but unfortunately it didn't help and I don't know what to do next.

I tried to fix this error, but then another one occurs:

> Modules vlcj.osx.stubs and uk.co.caprica.vlcj.osx.stubs export package
> com.apple.eawt to module vlcj.natives

Please help me to solve this error.

**pom.xml**

```
...

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    <javafx.version>18.0.1</javafx.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj-osx-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
            <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-module-infos</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-module-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <modules>
                            <module>
                                <artifact>
                                    <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.7.1</version>
                                </artifact>
                                <additionalDependencies>
                                    <dependency>
                                        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>vlcj-osx-stubs</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                                    </dependency>
                                </additionalDependencies>
                                <moduleInfo>
                                    <name>uk.co.caprica.vlcj</name>
                                    <exports>
                                        *;
                                    </exports>
                                </moduleInfo>
                            </module>
                            <module>
                                <artifact>
                                    <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>vlcj-javafx</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                                </artifact>
                                <moduleInfo>
                                    <name>uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx</name>
                                    <exports>
                                        *;
                                    </exports>
                                </moduleInfo>
                            </module>
                        </modules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
                        <version>4.7.1</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vlcj-javafx</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vlcj-osx-stubs</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <source>18</source>
                <target>18</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <mode>development</mode>
                        <url>${project.url}</url>
                        <key>value</key>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example/Main</mainClass>
                        <launcher>launcher</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>jlinkZipName</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>jlinkImageName</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        <compress>2</compress>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**module-info.java**

```
module com.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires jdk.jsobject;
    requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj;
    requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx;
    
    exports com.example;
}
```

**jdeps command**

```
jdeps --generate-module-info E:\Programming\IntelliJ\workspace\project\target\moditect --add-modules vlcj.natives,com.sun.jna,com.sun.jna.platform,vlcj.osx.stubs,uk.co.caprica.vlcj.osx.stubs --module-path C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\uk\co\caprica\vlcj-natives\4.1.0\vlcj-natives-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.2.0\jna-5.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.2.0\jna-platform-5.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\uk\co\caprica\vlcj-osx-stubs\1.0.0\vlcj-osx-stubs-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\uk\co\caprica\vlcj-osx-stubs\2.0.0\vlcj-osx-stubs-2.0.0.jar C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\uk\co\caprica\vlcj\4.7.1\vlcj-4.7.1.jar
```

Comment: Try the 4.8.x releases instead, I recently switched it to Java 11 and modules. There may be some further module-related issues so feel free to provide feedback at the project repo.

Comment: This answer is detailed and helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654791/10946427